# How do i put a Bitmap X position to a Integer or a Number?

Tags: actionscript-3

Assume that "temp1" is a Embedded Image and that it is given a x and y position.. I want to take its coordinates and put it into a integer.. I tried to look but theres no info and its obviously now working the way im doing it,
Heres how i did it..

```
public var temp1:Bitmap = new Bitmap()
public var t1:int;
public var image:MovieClip = new MovieClip()
public var eater:MovieClip = new MovieClip();

[Embed(source="Asset/Levels/Easy.swf")]
private var Easy:Class;

[Embed(source="Asset/Levels/Eat.swf")]
private var Eat:Class;

public class Game extends Sprite
{
    eater = new Eat();

    image = new Easy();
    image.x = 100;
    image.y = 100;
    stage.addChild(image);
    image.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, click);

}

public function click(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    temp1 = event.target.getChildAt(0);
    tester();
}

public function tester():void
{
    t1 = temp1.x;
    trace("t1 " + t1);
    eater.x = t1;
    stage.addChild(eater);
}
```

NOTE: This is only a example that i wrote to explain the situation im in..

I also tried it as a "Number" Variable instead of a "Integer".. 
After tracing it it just appears as "0"..

Reason why im doing this, is because ive got a array of Bitmaps on the stage.. Its a 6x6 grid of Bitmap images.. When i click a image on the stage i want to take its x, y coordinates and give it to a Integer.. so that i can cover the bitmap with a movieclip using the saved x and y position.. I've programmed it so that the image would disappear by time the movieclip file (Swf) has ended.. Problem is that when i do it, everything goes well except for the movieclip's x and y position.. It appears on the top left of stage..
I want it to be on the bitmap so using this formula i assumed it would work, but i just cant figure out why its not saving a x position.

Comment: you do realise that anything that will be instantiated e.g. `var temp1:Bitmap = new Bitmap();` and is DisplayObject will have x and y set as 0?

Comment: My apologies, I don't really understand what you mean..
Though i have attempted to explain,
I'll edit it and just add some extra code so everyone can understand it easily..

Answer (score 1):

I don't have Flash at hand here, but what happens when you change your `temp1` value to

```
temp1 = event.currentTarget as Bitmap;
```

Comment: Don't use getChildAt(0) - just get the target and the x and y should be valid.  Also, don't assign it as a global var, just handle all the code for getting the x and y and replacing the image in the handler.